# Formatting DDS Sine Wave output to unsigned decimal

Tags: verilog, sine, dds

Currently, I am working with the DDS core on Vivado, using Verilog, to generate a sign wave using a phase width of 7 and output width of 12. I understand that DDS formats the output in 2's complement / signed decimal. However, I am required to output only unsigned decimal through a DAC module.

The current unsigned decimal sine wave looks like this:
[image]

Desired output (currently in signed decimal):
[image]

What is the best way for me to offset the 2s complement output data to be just positive values from 0 to AMPLITUDE?

Comment: Just invert the MSB, or what am I missing? It's equivalent of adding 2^(n-1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add an offset of amplitude / 2.